# How many process builders can be active on per object

Tags: process-builder

How many process builders (all active) I can make on a single object?
Is there any limit like. I need to have N number of active process builders per object?

Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Process Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits.htm&type=5) documentation:

In *ENTERPRISE, UNLIMITED, PERFORMANCE, OR DEVELOPER EDITION*
Active record change processes and rules per object(rules include workflow rules, escalation rules, assignment rules, and auto-assignment rules.) is **50**.

Total processes **4,000** per process type

Active processes **2,000** per process type

Answer (score 1):

There can be `total of 50 active processes and rules per object`. Rules include workflow rules, escalation rules, assignment rules, and auto-assignment rules.

Attached is the image that states the number of active processes as per edition:

[image]

Reference: Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 0):

By default, it's 50 and it does include workflow rules, escalation rules, assignment rules, and auto-assignment rules along-with process.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits.htm&type=5

But it's soft limit and you can ask Salesforce to increase it upto 300 based on organization type: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000171161&language=en_US&type=1